# When i trying execute sql query appear error

Tags: python, mysql

Even so how to solve this problem:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Users AS t1
                          INNER JOIN Users_has_Users AS t ON t.Users_id = t1.id
                          INNER JOIN Users AS t2 ON t.Users_id1 = t2.id
                          WHERE t1.email = %s AND t1.id != t2.id AND t2.id >= %s
                          ORDER BY t2.name {}
                          LIMIT 10""".format(order), (email, since_id, limit))
```

Error:

```
not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use SQL parameters to interpolate anything other than *data*; you cannot use it for any SQL keywords such as `ASC`, nor the limit parameter. That is the *point* of SQL parameters; to avoid their values from being interpreted as SQL instead.

Use string formatting to interpolate your sort direction and query limit instead:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Users AS t1
                  INNER JOIN Users_has_Users AS t ON t.Users_id = t1.id
                  INNER JOIN Users AS t2 ON t.Users_id1 = t2.id
                  WHERE t1.email = %s AND t1.id != t2.id AND t2.id >= %s
                  ORDER BY t2.name {}
                  LIMIT {}""".format(order, limit), (email, since_id))
```

This does assume that you have full control over the contents of `order` and `limit`; never set it from user-supplied data as string formatting like this would open you up to a SQL injection attack otherwise.

Comment: It should be conveyed to the OP that using the order and/or limit like this must be done with care to avoid potential sql injection from unsanitized data.

Comment: @sberry: Indeed; I've altered the post since the LIMIT *is* a literal so as long as `limit` is an integer it should work (depending on the database adapter).

Comment: New problem: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @user3037421: My mistake; I used `?` instead of `%s` for your `limit` parameter there (different database engines use different SQL parameter placeholders).

Comment: And new error: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10'' at line 6")

Comment: @user3037421: Then the `limit` value was quoted as well; I guess that the limit value cannot be a SQL parameter either.

Comment: No, even I try to execute cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Users AS t1
                          INNER JOIN Users_has_Users AS t ON t.Users_id = t1.id
                          INNER JOIN Users AS t2 ON t.Users_id1 = t2.id
                          WHERE t1.email = %s AND t1.id != t2.id AND t2.id >= %s
                          ORDER BY t2.name {}
                          LIMIT 10""".format(order), (email, since_id, limit)) appear this error: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @user3037421: No, because now you have the extra `limit` parameter still, but no parameter placeholder in your query for it. Two `%s` and 3 values to interpolate.